# preg_match until end of string or other possibility

Tags: php, regex

Domingos: 10H00 a 20H00
or this one 
Domingos: 10H00 a 20H00.

I tried to preg match depending on wich of the two string is ultil the end of the string, or until the "."

I tried like this,but it's not working.

```
if(preg_match('/ingo(.*?)a(.*?)($|.)/is', $obj["horarios"], $horaDom){

}
```

The output that i want is: "10h00" and "20H00"

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Like [`'~^[^.]+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/gV2bG4/1)? What is the output you want to obtain?

Comment: WHat's not working exactly. The fullstop/period character in a RegEx means 'Any Character'. You need to escape it :

if(preg_match('/ingo(.*?)a(.*?)($|\.)/is', $obj["horarios"], $horaDom){

}

Comment: The output that i want is: "10h00" and "20H00"

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/(\d+H\d+)\s*a\s*(\d+H\d+)/
```

or even (to shorten the pattern, `(?1)` will reuse the pattern inside Group 1)

```
/(\d+H\d+)\s*a\s*((?1))/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV4qU4/1) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/xV4qU4/2)).

The `(\d+H\d+)` matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits, `H`, and 1 or more digits, `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces, `a` matches `a`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ZHrX07):

```
$re = '/(\d+H\d+)\s*a\s*((?1))/'; 
$str = "Domingos: 10H00 a 20H00\nDomingos: 10H00 a 20H00."; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this https://regex101.com/r/tD4sG0/1

```
(\d.*)?or|(\d.*)?\./g
```